# What's the difference between using OnPropertyChanged and Publishing in a WPF MVVM Prism application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm in the process of learning the MVVM pattern and Prism in a WPF application and I'm getting confused over when to just call OnPropertyChanged(MyProperty) and when to use the EventAggregator to publish an event. Doesn't the first already tell the world that MyProperty was changed so there is no need to call MyEvent.Instance.Publish(MyProperty). Or am I missing something completely?

```
 internal void OnSequenceSelected(object obj)
    {
        _currentSequence = obj as Sequence;
        Root = DocumentWrapper.Document.Sequences.Single(s => s.Name == _currentSequence.Name).TaskList.ToArray().ToTreeList();
        OnPropertyChanged("Root");
        LoadedGlobalEvent.Instance.Publish(Root);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnPropertyChanged is the event that must be called for your UI to update based on DataBinding.

Prism's Publish is a method associated to the EventAggregator which has nothing to do with MVVM.
It's just a design pattern that provides loose coupling between objects (i.e. view-models) when you want one object to respond to another object's behavior without the two knowing about each other.

I implemented this pub/sub pattern myself and called it a [messagebus](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Bizmonger.Patterns/).

Hence you can use the EventAggregator to publish messages regardless of MVVM concepts. Again, publishing a message is a completely separate and unrelated piece of your solution.